# unable to connect to hive using pyhive

Tags: python, hive, pyhive

I am getting "EOFError()" error while connecting to remove hiveserver2. My pyhive version is `0.6.1`

hiveserver2 is using http as the transport mode

This is the exception 
`ile "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 94, in connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 198, in __init__
    response = self._client.OpenSession(open_session_req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 187, in OpenSession
    return self.recv_OpenSession()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TCLIService/TCLIService.py", line 199, in recv_OpenSession
    (fname, mtype, rseqid) = iprot.readMessageBegin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py", line 148, in readMessageBegin
    name = self.trans.readAll(sz)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 65, in readAll
    raise EOFError()`

Also here is the code I am using to connect to remove hive

```
from pyhive import hive
from thrift.transport import THttpClient
host = 'xxx'
scheme = 'http'
path = '/cliservice'
port = ':' + str(10001)
http_uri = "{}://{}{}{}".format(scheme, host, port, path)
transport = THttpClient.THttpClient(http_uri)

username = 'xxx'
password = ''
if username or password:
    auth = base64.b64encode(username + ':' + password)
    transport.setCustomHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth})
connection = hive.connect(thrift_transport=transport)
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

pyhive has a simple connect method, did you give if a try.

```
from pyhive import hive
connection = hive.connect(host='HIVE_HOST',
                          port=10000,
                          database='temp',
                          username='HIVE_USERNAME',
                          password='HIVE_PASSWORD',
                          auth='CUSTOM')
```

Comment: This uses the binary mode of thrift.. but I am using http mode

Comment: Anyone found a solution for this? I'm getting same exception for similar setup. I have a sslTrustStore and sslTrustStorePassword parameters and I can connect successfully via beehive. The only difference is I'm trying to connect using overridden THttpClient constructor. ```transport = THttpClient.THttpClient(uri_or_host=host,
                                       port=port,
                                       path='cliservice',
                                       ssl_context=ssl_context)``` here ssl_context is `check_hostname=False` and `verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE`